# How to get folder sharing on Windows Mobile emulator to work

Tags: c++, mobile, windows-ce, emulation

I am developing an application using Windows Mobile 5.0, under embedded VC++ 4.0, and using the emulator for debugging.  I need to copy some files onto the emulator and planned on using the option to map a directory to the emulator storage card.  Problem is, this option is greyed out when I run the emulator. From the emulator help i get

*'On the Emulator, run a Windows CE OS that supports the ability to connect to a directory on the development workstation. '*

How do I accomplish this?  I have seen the command line option */sharedfolder*  but can't get at this from platform manager under EVC++ 4.0.  All comments welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the WinMo 5.0 SDK installed on Visual Studio 2005 and the option to map a directory works fine for me. I'd guess it's an issue related to eVC, which is pretty old by now. My recommendation is to try VS 2005 or 2008, there's a free 90-day trial you can download from microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/aa700831.aspx

Also, I'd note that VS is way better than eVC in many aspects. I used eVC and them moved to VS 2005, many "heavy templates" I had which wouldn't compile in eVC were compiled OK in VS 2005.